# Plot igraph data in C++ or C?

Tags: c++, c, igraph

Is there a tool or library which I can plot on C or C++ the vertex and edges of a graph like "plot" in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library

Comment: @nims: note that the poster meant graph as in "graph theory" and not as in "charts".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), a popular command-line graph drawing toolkit can theoretically be used as a [C library](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf) - although I have never tried it.